# Web API 2.0 - How to validate incoming Request in ASP.NET Web API similar in WCF AfterReceiveRequest(IDispatchMessageInspector member)

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I am migrating existing WCF service in to Web API. In WCF have implemented IDispatchMessageInspector Members for validating/Logging incoming request and outgoing reply. Like below

"#region IDispatchMessageInspector Members"

```
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        //Log the Request with Log4Net
        Logging.InfoMessage = string.Format("{0} - {1}", "Before calling ", GetWebMethodName());
        Logging.DebugMessage = request.ToString();
        Logging.WriteLog();

        //Logic to validate Request
        }
        return null;
    }        

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        //Log the Response with Log4Net
        Logging.DebugMessage = reply.ToString();
        Logging.InfoMessage = string.Format("{0} - {1}", "After called ", GetWebMethodName());
        Logging.WriteLog();
    }
```

#endregion

I would like to achieve the same in webAPI 2.0 . Doing this all the request validation handled Globally as well Logging.

Please share your experience if you have done already..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest creating a Custom Message Handler. A custom message handler is a class that inherits from the class **DelegatingHandler**.

All the request coming into a WebAPI request processing cycle are first handled by Request handlers and all the responses going out are lastly processed by handler.

https://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf

Comment: Yep, forgot that obvious one!  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

The `OnActionExecuting` occurs before the action method is invoked and `OnActionExecuted` just after. Look [here](http://damienbod.wordpress.com/2014/01/04/web-api-2-using-actionfilterattribute-overrideactionfiltersattribute-and-ioc-injection/) to have an example on how it could be implemented.

Another way could be to create your own Owin middleware. Look [here](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/07/owin-middleware-asp-net-web-api-and-clients-ip-address/) for a simple example that demonstrates how to perform some checks before invoking an action method.